# MaxConcurrentRequest in selfhost application

Tags: performance, iis, signalr, owin, self-hosting

I have a selfhost signalr application, everything is ok but when users become more than 5000, users reconnected rapidly. I know that defalt value of appConcurrentRequestLimit is 5000. and i run this:

```
cd %windir%\system32\inetsrv
appcmd.exe set config /section:system.webserver/serverRuntime /appConcurrentRequestLimit:100000
```

but nothing changed. I increased maxConcurrentRequestsPerCPU and requestQueueLimit according to [this](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/performance/signalr-performance)

but i have got problem yet.

i'm  using windows server 2012 and iis 8

Comment: can you provide more information about what happens when you have > 5000 users? What do you mean by reconnect? Are users seeing errors? Can you provide error detail or http error response they are getting?

Comment: any user can't connect to pusher and current users reconnected rapidly

Answer (score 0):

You are shooting in the dark here, and you have no data about the actual performance and what's happening. The users could reconnect because of different reasons (server timeouts, regular interval reconnects, server errors). There are countless possibilities.

The correct way to know what's happening and measure performance is to run a `Baseline` performance load test using the default configuration, and collect the relevant performance counters like **current requests, queued requests, current connections, max connections etc.**

You should also collect any relevant **Error logs** on the server that could help you figure out what's happening.

You can find the full list of performance counters you need below:

**Memory**

```
.NET CLR Memory# bytes in all Heaps (for w3wp)
```

**ASP.NET**

```
ASP.NET\Requests Current
ASP.NET\Queued
ASP.NET\Rejected
```

**CPU**

```
Processor Information\Processor Time
```

**TCP/IP**

```
TCPv6\Connections Established
TCPv4\Connections Established
```

**Web Service**

```
Web Service\Current Connections
Web Service\Maximum Connections
```

**Threading**

```
.NET CLR LocksAndThreads\ # of current logical Threads
.NET CLR LocksAndThreads\ # of current physical Threads
```

Once you have your baseline performance results on a graph, then you can modify configuration (e.g. modify the number of concurrent requests like you tried above) and then re-run your test, and collect again the same performance counters.

**The performance counter results will speak for themselves, and they will lead you to a solution.**

You can generate the load with a tool like **Crank**:

https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/tree/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Crank

In addition you can also check the SignalR troubleshooting guide:

http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/testing-and-debugging/troubleshooting